# Is there any method or tool to get a blend color code with transparent

Tags: html, css, colors

says, the color code of a wrapper is #8e3e59. and the color code of a box in the wrapper is rgba(0,0,0,0.5). If I use a colorpicker to test the box is #723247

Is there any method or tool to calculate the result #723247 from #8e3e59 and rgba(0,0,0,0.5)

Comment: The key term you should look for is "blend", not "merge".

Comment: Sorry, my description is not clear enough. I need to blend the color which contain transparent. but the duplicate question is just two rgb color.

Comment: The answers list several possibilities, with alpha, without it, averaging, adding, ...